# Android wear - how to capture touch events

Tags: touch, wear-os

I want to capture the touch events on Android wear (I am using Samsung Gear Live) to draw the trajectory of touch. I tried to capture onTouch event and onGenericMotionEvent event as the following code, but the event is triggered only one time or sometimes does not happen while I swiping on the screen. I need more touch events (at least 5 to 6 events when I swipe left to right) to draw the trajectory. How I can capture enough touch events on Android Wear screen?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
            container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    String s = "";
                    s += "action=" + event.getAction();
                    s += ", X=" + event.getX();
                    s += ", Y=" + event.getY();
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            container.setOnGenericMotionListener(new View.OnGenericMotionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onGenericMotion(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    String s = "";
                    s += "action=" + event.getAction();
                    s += ", X=" + event.getX();
                    s += ", Y=" + event.getY();
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try using only:

```
container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
```

and `return true` from there? You need to inform the `View` you consumed the event.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to debug offline you can get the touch co-ordinates from adb:-

```
adb shell getevent
```