# Android Capture touches coordinates in whole device

Tags: java, android, android-service, touch-event, rooted-device

I want to capture the pointer locations in whole android device by providing a `service` to develop something like `Pointer Location` in `Developer options` .
 First I have tried adding`overlay view` which is always on top to capture the coordinates . but this method didn't let me to get touch events in `move actions` . 
So I decided to try another way . At last I found that for `rooted` devices , we can get touch events but I don't know how . Could you please give some suggestions ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Check out this ans:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464834/android-wear-how-to-capture-touch-events/42989092#42989092

Comment: Check the ans here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464834/android-wear-how-to-capture-touch-events/42989092#42989092

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for this answer as well. Can you specify how you did the overlay view and captured the coordinates?

I was able to do the overlay as well, with some other answers from here on stackOverFlow, but if I capture the Overlay coordinates, it renders the background/OS useless. Its one or the other, not an actual service in the background running or an overlay recording coords. Its one, or the other.

I have read that this goes against the Android security framework, since it would be a really big flaw when exploited. Although, everything that I have read is from 2012 at the earliest. This is the newest post in 3 years. Any insight?