# Android watch is not detecting touchevents on GridViewPager

Tags: java, android, touch, wear-os

I tried to implement a DismissOverlay for my Android Watch application, but it didn't work. So I tried to tear the problem down and implemented the most basic thing related to touch gestures I was aware about :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    switch (action) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was DOWN");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was MOVE");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was UP");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL):
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was CANCEL");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE):
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                    "of current screen element");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

But this dooesn't recognize anything.
So I'm curious if there is something simple I did wrong, or some special stuff related to the watch implementation I have to take care about?

Comment: Did you try using .setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){?
 Try to check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464834/android-wear-how-to-capture-touch-events) for additonal info.

Comment: I just solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was, that I had a `GridViewPager` and I tried to get the touchEvents directly from that. But you actually have to implement the touch stuff for the `GridViewPagerItem`.